# Retrieve localStorage data in "start/stop" timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, local-storage, setinterval

I'm trying to retrieve `localStorage` data in a **Start/Stop** timer. My goal is to have the timer start automatically on page load but when the user leaves and comes back at a later date *(page refresh)*, the timer will resume where it left off.

I'm close to getting this to work..but after each page refresh it starts back to `00:00:00`.

I created a `setTimeout` function w/ a 3 second delay to illustrate that *some* of this is working.

Many thanks to anyone that can help put me on the right track.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/WdeowQ)

---

**HTML**

```
<!-- Timer -->
<div class="time-wrapper">
  <strong>Time</strong>
  <span id="time-total">00:00:00</span>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button id="start-timer" class="button">Start</button>
    <button id="pause-timer" class="button">Pause</button>
</div>
```

**JS** *(with [EasyTimer.js](https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/) plugin)*

```
/* Create Timer
********************************/
var timer = new Timer();

var timeTotal = $('#time-total'),
    timeKey = 'time_stored',
    timeStored = localStorage.getItem(timeKey);

// Update Event
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    $(timeTotal).html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});

// Started Event
timer.addEventListener('started', function (e) {
    $(timeTotal).html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});

// Start Timer
$('#start-timer').click(function () { timer.start(); });
$('#pause-timer').click(function () { timer.pause(); });

/* When page loads
********************************/
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {
        localStorage.setItem(timeKey, timeTotal.text());
    }, 500);

    if (timeStored) {
        timeTotal.text(timeStored);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#start-timer').click();
        timer.start();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value when you start the timer - see my example below. You might want to adjust the functionality of Start button accordingly, as it also calls the start() method of the timer. Please note i used different key for your localStorage (just in case you already have a set value in your browser) and i store only seconds which gets incremented everytime the event `secondsUpdated` is fired. There is no need for your own setInterval, as you can use the interval of the timer fired with the above mentioned event.

```
var timer = new Timer();

var timeTotal = $('#time-total'),
timeKey = 'time_stored_seconds',
timeStored = localStorage.getItem(timeKey);

// Update Event
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    var newValue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(timeKey) | 0)+1
    localStorage.setItem(timeKey, newValue);
    $(timeTotal).html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});

// Started Event
timer.addEventListener('started', function (e) {
    $(timeTotal).html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});

// Start Timer
$('#start-timer').click(function () { timer.start(); });
$('#pause-timer').click(function () { timer.pause(); });

/* When page loads
********************************/
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (timeStored) {

        timeTotal.text(timeStored);
    }else{
        localStorage.setItem(timeKey, 0);
        timeStored = 0
    }

    timer.start({ precision: 'seconds', startValues: {seconds: parseInt(timeStored)}});

});
```

Comment: I tried your code, but the timer isn't accurate when you refresh the page. It looks like it's about 4 to 5 seconds behind each time..any idea what might be happening? I created a test codepen w/ your code inside to show you the issue: https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/xpKPxM

Comment: my bad sorry - please see the updated code. I modified the secondsUpdated handler to fix the issue

Comment: no problem! just tested and it's working like a charm.